# Continue output on same line

Tags: bash

Want to do a fancy effect by printing [OK] at the end of the last line when a task is finished.

Got this:

```
echo "$0: Starting backup process in '$backupdir'... " 
sleep 3
echo '[OK]'
```

I tried different things at the end of the first echo, at the beginning of the second like `\r`, `\c`, `\`, Googled it... No good.

I want it to output this:

`./backup.sh: Starting backup process in '/backup'...`

... And 3 sec later, add the `[OK]`:

`./backup.sh: Starting backup process in '/backup'... [OK]`

Thanks,

Comment: Please don't use `echo`, stick to `printf`, read http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html for more information to why.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use the `-n` option to skip printing newline at the end. More reference at [`echo` docs](http://ss64.com/bash/echo.html).

So you could do something like this:

```
echo -n "$0: Starting backup process in '$backupdir'... "
```

Answer (score 17):

use the more portable `printf`:

```sh
printf "%s" "$0: Starting backup process in '$backupdir'... "
sleep 3
printf '[OK]\n'
```

Comment: Some implementations of echo use the `-n` flag to suppress the newline; others use `\c` at the end of the string.  If you use one in your script, and echo expects the other, you'll get "-n " in front of your output, or "\c" at the end.  But `printf "%s" "$0: ..."` will always work as expected.

Comment: @Gordon Davisson @ghostdog74, Could not agree more, even the POSIX standard says "New applications are encouraged to use printf  instead of echo.". +1

Answer (score 2):

`echo -n hello`