# How to continue log on same line in Java?

Tags: java, logging, testng

This is similar to [this question, which is about a bash file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372673/continue-output-on-same-line).

We've created a log which outputs to the console while we're running our TestNG tests:

```
private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(xyz.class);
```

Later on, during the tests, the log is filled with details to let us know what exactly is being done:

```
log.info("Setting browser...");
this.browser = browser;
log.info("Completed.");
```

Right now it's printing out as you would expect:

```
Setting browser...
Completed.
```

I'd like to have this print out on the same line:

```
Setting browser...
```

and a few milliseconds later:

```
Setting browser...Completed.
```

Is this possible with the LogFactory?

Comment: How would people be able to answer this when you have not told them what logging framework you are using?

Comment: @oxbow_lakes It looks like he is using one from Apache.

Comment: In our Maven Dependencies, I'm seeing Log4J, but when I press F3 it takes me to commons-logging, so I'm thinking @ColinD is correct.

Comment: commons-logging is an *interface* which requires an underlying implementation, which is therefore presumably Log4J. See my answer below for how to do this (although there's a drawback)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without knowing precisely which **logging library** you are using, I would guess that the answer is almost certainly *not unless you want to explicitly specify a newline character everywhere else*.

The `java.util.logging` (and `Log4J`) frameworks allow you to plugin formatters to format your statements. You'd need to specify a format which did not end with a newline character. For example, in [**Log4J**](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html). they give an example pattern as

```
 %-5p [%t]: %m%n
```

So if you removed *everything except* the `%m` (the `%n` is the newline and the other stuff includes the time and log-level; `%t` and `%p` respectively, I think), newlines would not be automatically appended to each statement.

However, this means that everywhere else, your other log statements would have to look like this:

```
log.info("I want this on one line\n");
```

Comment: Don't know why it was downvoted, but it *would* dump the time, thread, etc. for each msg without the newline on the same line, making it illegible, and breaking log analysis tools.

Comment: was downvoted, due to the fact that all it was asking was for something you already put in a comment (ie not useful). downvote removed and given +1 as question has evolved and this is now an answer.

Comment: Colin, that's just not true; look in the version history. The original answer mentioned pretty much all the current one does

Comment: @ColinD It is generally not fair to downvote before leaving a comment and at least 5 minutes grace period for the answerer to respond.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I will try and follow that in the future. owbow_lakes, you are right... weird. All I remember seeing was the same text you had used as a comment as an answer.

Comment: But without the timestamp etc. it's much, *much* less useful, and a variety of log analysis tools still wouldn't work well. It's still a valid solution, but imo the tradeoffs make it a sub-optimal one.

Comment: I agree, Dave - it is not worth the bother

Answer (score 4):

Leave the log alone. If you want it more readable, post-process it.

Messing with the log file will lose information unless you are careful. Look at timestamps as an example. If your `Setting browswer..` log statement has a timestamp included, putting the `completed` statement without its timestamp is a loss of information and having two timestamps on the same line does not seem natural.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple alternative that doesn't require any change in the logger configuration if you use the `slf4j-api` with the `logback` implementation.

It can be achieved by using the `Logger.printf` method, like so:

**Imports**

```
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

...
```

**Logger instance**

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(YourClass.class)

...
```

**Inside a loop**

```
...

log.printf("> Processed %d/%d\r", ++yourCounter, maxCounter) // Will log in the same line due to \r

...
```

**Sample Output**

```
22:12:15.169 [main] INFO  your.package.YourClass - Previous log output a...
22:12:15.170 [main] INFO  your.package.YourClass - Previous log output b...
22:12:15.170 [main] INFO  your.package.YourClass - Previous log output c...
> Processed 1398/4096
```